# How to set up phpimagik in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, imagick

Can anyone tell me simple step by step to set up phpimagick in OS X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use `homebrew`. Go to the [homebrew website](http://brew.sh) and install it with the one line script there. - I don't want to paste it here because you need the latest and greatest line at the time of following these instructions.

Then, when you have `homebrew` installed, do these steps to get ImageMagick installed and running under PHP and also with Apache.

```
# Check all of homebrew is working - fix any errors before proceeding
brew doctor

# Get latest versions of everything if you already had "homebrew" installed
# Probably not necessary if you just installed "homebrew" in previous step
brew update && brew upgrade

# Find latest PHP version - using "brew search"
newestPHP=$(brew search php | grep -E "php[0-9]+$" | sort | tail -1)
echo $newestPHP

e.g. php56

# Install latest PHP and corresponding ImageMagick
brew install ${newestPHP} ${newestPHP}-imagick

e.g. brew install php56 php56-imagick

# Check that the installation worked - you MUST use "/usr/local/bin/php"
/usr/local/bin/php -i | grep -i imag
```

**Output**

```
Additional .ini files parsed => /usr/local/etc/php/5.6/conf.d/ext-imagick.ini
PHP Warning:  Unknown: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in Unknown on line 0
imagick
imagick module => enabled
imagick module version => 3.1.2
imagick classes => Imagick, ImagickDraw, ImagickPixel, ImagickPixelIterator
ImageMagick version => ImageMagick 6.9.1-1 Q16 x86_64 2015-04-15 http://www.imagemagick.org
ImageMagick copyright => Copyright (C) 1999-2015 ImageMagick Studio LLC
ImageMagick release date => 2015-04-15
ImageMagick number of supported formats:  => 204
ImageMagick supported formats => 3FR, AAI, AI, ART, ARW, AVI, AVS, BGR, BGRA, BGRO, BMP, BMP2, BMP3, BRF, CAL, CALS, CANVAS, CAPTION, CIN, CIP, CLIP, CMYK, CMYKA, CR2, CRW, CUR, CUT, DCM, DCR, DCX, DDS, DFONT, DNG, DOT, DPX, DXT1, DXT5, EPDF, EPI, EPS, EPS2, EPS3, EPSF, EPSI, ERF, FAX, FITS, FRACTAL, FTS, G3, GIF, GIF87, GRADIENT, GRAY, GV, HALD, HDR, HISTOGRAM, HRZ, HTM, HTML, ICB, ICO, ICON, IIQ, INFO, INLINE, IPL, ISOBRL, JNG, JNX, JPE, JPEG, JPG, JPS, JSON, K25, KDC, LABEL, M2V, M4V, MAC, MAP, MASK, MAT, MATTE, MEF, MIFF, MKV, MNG, MONO, MOV, MP4, MPC, MPEG, MPG, MRW, MSL, MSVG, MTV, MVG, NEF, NRW, NULL, ORF, OTB, OTF, PAL, PALM, PAM, PANGO, PATTERN, PBM, PCD, PCDS, PCL, PCT, PCX, PDB, PDF, PDFA, PEF, PES, PFA, PFB, PFM, PGM, PICON, PICT, PIX, PJPEG, PLASMA, PNG, PNG00, PNG24, PNG32, PNG48, PNG64, PNG8, PNM, PPM, PREVIEW, PS, PS2, PS3, PSB, PSD, PWP, RADIAL-GRADIENT, RAF, RAS, RAW, RGB, RGBA, RGBO, RGF, RLA, RLE, RMF, RW2, SCR, SCT, SFW, SGI, SHTML, SIX, SIXEL, SPARSE-COLOR, SR2, SRF, STEGANO, SUN, SVG, SVGZ, TEXT, TGA, THUMBNAIL, TILE, TIM, TTC, TTF, TXT, UBRL, UIL, UYVY, VDA, VICAR, VID, VIFF, VIPS, VST, WBMP, WMV, WPG, X3F, XBM, XC, XCF, XPM, XPS, XV, YCbCr, YCbCrA, YUV
imagick.locale_fix => 0 => 0
imagick.progress_monitor => 0 => 0
```

That completes the installation if you only want to run ImageMagick under PHP ***outside your website***.

The remaining steps are only necessary if you want to run PHP and ImageMagick ***under Apache inside your website***.

```
# Check if PHP module loaded in Apache config file - /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
grep "^LoadModule.*php5_module.*libphp.*" /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
Check it matches, or if not present add a line like this
LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.6/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so

# Restart Apache
sudo apachectl restart
```